# Can I do Aqiqa of my Elder sister?

Tags: aqeeqah

Assalamu alaykum, Can I do Aqiqa of my Elder sister?

As our parents didn't do ours, I was thinking of doing hers (32 years F) first, then mine afterward (28 years M)

Second, how should one do Aqiqa? just go buy the goat, make intention in heart and slay it

or

There is specific Dua which is must to be done before, can you mention that aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqeeqah is to due on the father of a child. The Shafi'is have stated that it can also be done by the guardian on whom the child's financial maintenance is obligatory, and that if a person has become an adult then he should do his own aqeeqah - in which case your sister can perhaps fund the sacrifice and you can act as her agent with her permission. Other than this some madhabs allow for a different person to do aqeeqah if the father gives its permission or has already passed away.

As for the method then it is analogous to udhiyyah i.e. the sacrifice done on eid al-adha, the major requirements being:

- you select a suitable goat (or two goats for a male depending on the madhab) which fulfills the quality and age requirements of udhiyyah
- the slaughtering must be done yourself or at the hands of a Muslim
- you pronounce the name of Allah while slaughtering
- you make the intention of doing aqeeqah for the said person
- you slaughter it by slicing its throat from the front, cutting open the two main arteries and veins and the windpipe and esophagus
- The meat, hide and anything else from the carcass is to be consumed and distributed in the same way as that of udhiyyah. It can not be sold.

Saying the following is recommended:

> وَقُولُوا: بِسْمِ اللهِ وَاللهُ أَكْبَرُ، اللهُمَّ لَكَ وَإِلَيْكَ، هَذِهِ عَقِيقَةُ فُلَانٍ
>
> Say: In the name of Allah and Allah is great, O Allah this is for you, this is the aqeeqah for so and so (person whose aqeeqah is being done)
>
> <sup>— [Sunan al-Kubra al-Bayhaqi](https://shamela.ws/book/7861/21955#p1)</sup>

Ref: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/301474/ and [Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/19290) and https://islamqa.info/en/answers/96462/